# Azure Table on Azure Automation

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-automation

We're trying to perform Azure Table data operations from Azure Automation. Currently using Powershell 7.1 and have installed module AzTable. The following works:

```
$azureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
$azureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $azureContext
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount

$table = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageContext).CloudTable
```

But when trying a data operation such as

```
Add-AzTableRow -Table $table -partitionKey "1" -rowKey ("key1") -property @{"prop1"="test1";"prop2"="test2"}
```

We end up with exceptions such as

MethodInvocationException: C:\ModulesV2\User\AzTable\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:266
Line |
266 |  …      return ($Table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperat …
|                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The specified resource does not exist."

We will try to use $table.ExecuteBatch() but that also fails. We're missing some dependencies but can't figure out which. This is a vanilla Azure Automation account we just created.

Should this be supported?

Answer (score 0):

Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The specified resource does not exist."

As mentioned in error the Add-AzTableRow is not getting the table which you are specifying

As mentioned in Microsoft Document,

Using the CloudTable property is mandatory when working with table data via the AzTable PowerShell module.

- While using AzTable to work on a table, it is mandatory to use CloudTable property.
- The .Net methods accessible for handling table data from PowerShell are exposed through the CloudTable property.

Example code:

```html
$cloudTable = $storageTable.CloudTable
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#reference-the-cloudtable-property-of-a-specific-table

Comment: Thanks! As I wrote I am getting a valid table reference back. It's not an issue with connection, permissions or whether the table exists or not. It's when starting to query/update data it constantly fails. Creating a blank runbook, importing AzTable and try to add a row doesn't work. PowerShell 7.1. 

I'm trying to figure out which dependencies are missing when running in Azure Automation as it works locally.